# BindingSource.Find searching for value in DataSet("Table")

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to find a value contained in a `DataSet.Tables("TableName")` in a `BindingSource`.

```
 'Going through each row in my BindingSource
 For Each row As DataRowView In myBindingSource
      Dim IDNum As Integer = myBindingSource.Find("myIDNum", DataSet.Tables("TableName").Rows("myIDNum"))

      'If IDNum has been found
      If IDNum >= 0 Then
           If FACID("ColumnName").ToString = "Something" Then
                DirectCast(myBindingSource(row), DataRowView)("Column") = "Something else"
           End If
      'If IDNum has not been found
      Else
           myBindingSource.AddNew()
           'Other stuff
      End If
 Next
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with the third line:

```
 Dim IDNum As Integer = myBindingSource.Find("myIDNum", DataSet.Tables("TableName").Rows("myIDNum"))
```

Does anyone know how to make this line work? I'm not sure how to do a .find with a row from a DataSet.Table.

**Edit:
After a second look, I think in order to find my DataSet value within the BindingSource, it should look something like the below, but the structure of this line is wrong:**

```
  Dim IDNum As Integer = myBindingSource.Find(DataSet.Tables("TableName").Columns("myIDNum"), row(myIDNum))
```

Comment: `DataSet.Tables("ColumnName")` will return a **table** named `ColumnName`, not a column. Is that really what you expected? Also, it seems like the names used in this code are not consistent. Can you clean those up? We won't be able to get the correct meaning of what you're trying to do if we can't understand what each of the variables refers to.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Oops...No, sorry that was just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the `For` loop:

```
IDNum As DataRowView
```

is immediately followed by this:

```
Dim IDNum As Integer
```

That's attempting to give two variables the same name. *Don't do that.* Based on how things are used, I think you want a different name for the loop variable. Combine that with the problem line from the question:

```
For Each row As DataRowView In myBindingSource
    Dim IDNum As Integer = ImportBS.Find("myIDNum", row("myIDNum"))
```

Just be careful with this. The result of this code is an **index**, not an ID number, and those are not the same thing!

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for the reply! I've renamed those as you suggested! The other bit with the code - that BindingSource.Find should actually read myBindingSource.Find haha. I'll update the original post to clarify. I'm trying to find a value inside my DataSet("TableName") column named "myIDNum" in myBindingSource, if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, I'm stupid. I just realized what I did - long day. Thank you. Going to mark this as answer because it helped me realize how stupid I am.